# How to build traversing tree?

Tags: php, arrays, function, recursion, tree

I am working on tree formatting of an associative array:

```
Array
(
    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => David Clance
            [designation] => Chief Executive Officer
            [member] => Array
                (
                    [62] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Sonali Yadav
                            [designation] => Managing Director
                            [member] => Array
                                (
                                    [1147] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => Samina Falgun
                                            [designation] => Associate Technical Product Manager
                                            [member] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [676] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [name] => Rushi Vyas
                                                            [designation] => Team Lead
                                                            [member] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [946] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [name] => Vijay Gade
                                                                            [designation] => Software Engineer
                                                                            [member] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                ) 
                                                                        ) 
                                                                )
                                                        )

                                                    [1497] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [name] => Pranali Dighe
                                                            [designation] => Software Engineer
                                                            [member] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                ) 
                                                        )
                                                ) 
                                        )

                                    [2882] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => Akash Meheta
                                            [designation] => Manager - Administrations
                                            [member] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [972] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [name] => Rajendra Gore
                                                            [designation] => Office Assistant
                                                            [member] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                ) 
                                                        )
                                                ) 
                                        )
                                    )
                        )
                    [189] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Dharmendra Shroff
                            [designation] => Director Of Engineering
                            [member] => Array
                                (
                                    [443] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => James Bond
                                            [designation] => Software Development Manager
                                            [member] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )
                                 )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

On the basis of `['member']` key, I'm trying to display the tree structure in parent-child formation like:

```
David Clance
    Sonali Yadav
        Samina Falgun
            Rushi Vyas
                Vijay Gade
            Pranali Dighe
        Akash Meheta
            Rajendra Gore
    Dharmendra Shroff
        James Bond
```

I have code like below to get the incremented row count for every array element and column count to tab values in array:

```
    $this->m_intRowCount = 1;
    $intColumnCount = 0;

    public function handle() {
        if( true == valArr( $this->m_arrmixEmployees ) ) {
            $this->getEmployeeDetails( $this->m_arrmixEmployees, $intColumnCount );
        }
    }

    public function getEmployeeDetails( $arrmixEmployees, $intColumnCount ) {
        foreach( $arrmixEmployees as $keys => $values ) {

            $this->m_intRowCount++; 
            echo $values['name'] . " " . $values['designation'];

            if( true == valArr( $values['member'] ) ) {
                echo "<br>";
                $intColumnCount++;

                foreach( $values['member'] as $key => $value ) {
                    $this->m_intRowCount++;

                    echo $value['name'] . " " . $value['designation'];

                    if( true == valArr( $value['member'] ) ) {
                        echo "<br>";
                        $intColumnCount++;
                        $this->getEmployeeDetails( $value['member'], $intColumnCount );
                        $intColumnCount--;
                    } else {
                        echo "<br>";
                    }

                }
            } else {
                echo "<br>";
                continue;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: And the million dollar question is?

Comment: @Epodax: On the basis of ['member'] key, trying to display tree structure in parent-child formation like I have displayed in question. but getting some unordered sequence. can you help me in this recursive function?

Comment: @Epodax: And what you cant of this?

Comment: @Epodax it turns out like this :)

Comment: I was mistaken in adress. Wanted to write to asker :)

Answer (score 1):

Make it easy

```
function out($in, $space) {
  foreach($in as $arr) {
    echo $space.$arr['name']."\n";
    if (is_array($arr['member']) && count($arr['member'])) out($arr['member'], $space."   ");
  }  
}

out($array, '');
```